# Почему Android VK SDK при вызове крашит VKSdk.initialize(this)?

Tags: java, android, вконтакте

Сабж. писал приложение 3 дня. На 4й включив студию, и запустив проект словил краш 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: VKSdk.initialize(Context) must be call from Application#onCreate(). 
Код где вызываю метод:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VKSdk.initialize(this);
}
```

Создал новый проект в студии, и нуже на чистом непаханном поле, запустил метод, и он так же открашился. Создал новое приложение в Vk developer, всё тоже самое. естественно фингерпринт названия пакетов и MainActivity правильные. Даже поудалял все приложения которые там были у меня, и создал одно новое, заполнил, и опять краш. Тестил на 2х устройствах.

```
08-25 12:56:33.588  12482-12482/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vktab/com.vktab.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: VKSdk.initialize(Context) must be call from Application#onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5132)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: VKSdk.initialize(Context) must be call from Application#onCreate()
        at com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.initialize(VKSdk.java:136)
        at com.vktab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5132)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: пробовали эти две строки `    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VKSdk.initialize(this);` поменять местами?

Comment: @KoVadim    Только что, в новом проекте, попробовал, к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: А вызываете с кода активити?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, вот весь код MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        VKSdk.initialize(this);

    }
}

Comment: А в ошибке сказано что нужно совсем в другом месте добавлять. В Вашем коде должно быть место вида `public class MainApp extends Application`. В этом файле и нужно добавлять.

Comment: @KoVadim Так ведь всё работало и из "этого места" несколько дней назад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло описание этого метода в классе унаследованном от Application.
Ссылки:
https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/200eaaeede8db68af8dae2c3f927fbb02aedfa63/VKTestApplication/src/main/java/com/vk/vktestapp/Application.java

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android

Answer (score 7):

Создаем новый класс в проекте наследующий `Application()`. Переносим инициализацию `VKSDK` в этот файл.

Пример на `Kotlin`:

```
public class MyApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        VKSdk.initialize(this)
    }
}
```

И дописываем в манифесте название аппликации

```
...
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
...
```